# Three shooters shoot at the same target, each of them shoots just once.

Tags: probability

Three shooters shoot at the same target, each of them shoots just once. The three of them respectively hit the target with a probability of 60%, 70%, and 80%. What is the probability that the shooters will hit the target

a) at least once

b) at least twice

---

I have an approach to this but I'm not sure if there's just a formula for this type of thing. For part (a) I was thinking of simply adding the probability of all of the valid scenarios. For instance $$[P(A)*(1-P(B))*(1-P(C))]+[(1-P(A))*P(B)*(1-P(C))]+...$$

and so on until I cover all scenarios in which "at least one" hits. Is there a simpler way? (i assume this would also apply to part b)

Comment: Hint for the first part:  it's easier to compute the probability that they all miss.

Comment: i see. are you saying this because there are less probabilities to calculate? duh!

Comment: Yes...and the event "at least one person hits" is the complimentary event to the event "nobody hits".

Comment: thank you for this!

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be the number of times the target is hit. The probability $P(X \ge 1)$ then equals 1 minus the probability of missing the target three times:

$$P(X \ge 1) = 1 - (1 - P(A)) (1 - P(B)) (1 - P(C)) = 1 - 0.4 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.2 = 0.976$$

To find the probability $P(X \ge 2)$ of hitting the target at least twice, you can consider two cases: either two people hit the target and one does not, or all people hit the target. We find:

$$P(X \ge 2) = 0.4 \cdot 0.7 \cdot 0.8 + 0.6 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.8 + 0.6 \cdot 0.7 \cdot 0.2 +  0.6 \cdot 0.7 \cdot 0.8 = 0.788$$

Answer (score 0):

"a) at least once".  Writing "H" for a hit and "M" for a miss, and writing hits and misses in the order "ABC" there are 3 possibilities:
HMM: probability is (0.6)(0.3)(0.2)= 0.036
MHM: probability is (0.4)(0.7)(0.2)= 0.056
MMH: probability is (0.4)(0.3)(0.8)= 0.096
The probability of any one of these happening is 0.036+ 0.056+ 0.096= 0.188.

"b) at least twice".  These are 
HHM: probability is (0.6)(0.7)(0.2)= 0.084
HMH: probability is (0.6)(0.3)(0.8)= 0.144
MHH: probability is (0.4)(0.7)(0.8)= 0.224
The probability of any one of these happening is 0.084+ 0.144+ 0.224= 0.452.

"c) all three".  This is
HHH: probability is (0.6)(0.7)(0.8)= 0.336.

Comment: for part a i think you are forgetting about the HHM, HMH, MHH, and HHH scenarios. for part b think you are forgetting about the HHH scenario.

Comment: You are right.  I gave "exactly  one" rather than "at least one".  The obvious way to do that is to subtract P(MMM) from 1.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the polynomial
$$P(x)=(0.4\, +0.6 x) (0.3\, +0.7 x) (0.2\, +0.8 x)$$
The neat thing about $P(x)$ is that when expanded it gives all you could possibly want to know about the probabilities of the number of shooters hitting the target:
$$P(x) = 0.024\, +0.188 x+0.452 x^2+0.336 x^3$$
The coefficient of $x^n$ in $P(x)$ is the probability that exactly $n$ shooters will hit the target, for $n=0,1,2,3$.  I.e., the probability that zero shooters will hit the target is 0.024, that one shooter will hit the target is 0.188, that two shooters will hit the target is 0.452, and that three shooters will hit the target is 0.336.

This method is especially attractive if you have a computer algebra system, but in small examples like this one hand computation is also easy.